# How to add a border around a row/column in a d3 heatmap?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, heatmap

I want to add a border around the row in the following manner (the hovered cell has its own stroke):

[image: What I want]

However, I'm only able to do this:

[image]

To create the heatmap I just used the example code from the https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_basic.html webpage.

Here's how I'm currently adding the strokes:

```
svg_heatmap.selectAll("rect")
            .style("stroke", "none")
            .filter(d => d.group == this.__data__.group || d.variable == this.__data__.variable)
            .style("stroke", "black")
```

I've tried messing with `stroke-dasharray` but to no avail. I'm kinda stumped here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra rect for each row/column.

Based on the example code from https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_basic.html webpage, you can try to do the following.

```js
svg.selectAll()
      .data(myVars)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("y", d => y(d))
      .attr("x", x("A"))
      .attr("width", (x.step()) * myGroups.length)
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "black")
```